# Change mode of the getDefaultPreference file in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using a `PreferenceActivity` to save some user preferences.
I want to access the default Preference file from outside the app for debugging purposes.

How can I change the `defaultSharedPreferences` file from private to public mode?
And also what is the default name of that defaultSharedPreference file?

[EDIT]

One negative vote that means something is wrong with the question.
At least, do let me know whats wrong!
That would be less cruel and not discouraging for a newbie like me :)

Answer (score 1):

In the DDMS (or its equivalent, in Android Studio), the path to your preference file is `/data/data/your.app.name/shared_prefs/your.app.name_preferences.xml`.
You can export it, modify it, and even reimport it (**at your own risk!**).

---

EDIT

The path is correct, the file name might vary.

[image]

Sorry, I wasn't pointing the xml file, while taking the screen shot.
But it's there.

Comment: No such path exist. Infact there is no such file or folder that has the name of my app. Well the app is working perfectly.

Comment: The **path** is correct. The **file name** might vary.

Comment: This is so simple, yet im stuck. I fear  im doing something terribly wrong

Comment: I added a picture to my answer. Maybe it's worth 1000 words. Sorry I wasn't pointing the xml file, but it's there.

Comment: Nothing would have help me more then the pic, but I am facing a weird problem. I am not able to explore folders in android studio Android Device Monitor. What could be the possible reason? This was a totally different problem so I elaborated it here with the pic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275988/android-studio-android-device-monitors-file-explorer-not-working/32276097#32276097

Comment: All done. I started using [root] adbd Insecure and now everything is working. THanks