# Android Studio - Android Device Monitor's File explorer not working

Tags: android, file, debugging, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I have just learnt using `preferences` in Android. For debugging purpose I need to access the preferences files. I googled and found the default location of the preference file and also how to access it via Android Device Monitor.

Somehow I am not able to open any folders under the File explorer tab of the Android device monitor. They just aren't responding. I tried waiting for ADM to load and tried again but no success. (Double click on folder is not working, STRANGE!)

Do we need to configure before using it? I am using Android studio. 
Any help would be appreciated. 
Attaching image
[image: Android Device Monitor screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I found how to make it work.

goto run -> location where your adb is

Ex: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

type `adb root` , `Enter` (Your phone must have root)

If this doesn't work, install this app on your phone: [[root] adbd Insecure](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.adbd&hl=en) or its free alternative [here](http://dl-1.va.us.xda-developers.com/3/0/0/8/5/2/7/adbd-Insecure-v2.00.apk?key=6CxkVXcMpAzIUC2CWbJ7ig&ts=1440784997) (*update: link broken now*).

Get more info at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1687590

Answer (score 0):

You will need either to use the emulator or to have a rooted phone to use all functionalities.

Comment: what is rooted phone ?? I have same issue and want to see tombstone, but in file explorer, data folder I dont see any tombstones.. !!

Answer (score -1):

Root your device and open adb shell and change the permissions as:

$ adb shell
$ su
1|root@android:/ # chmod -R 777 data/