# Android device Monitor's File explorer is not working properly

Tags: android-studio

I am using Android studio 2.2.2. My android device monitor's File explorer is not running properly, as it is not displaying any files.

[image]

Comment: please restart you emulator else see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275988/android-studio-android-device-monitors-file-explorer-not-working

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug for +24 emulator as it is described [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225049). Check your emulator version and try to run in a lower emulator. 23 for example.